# Custom content type attached to reusable workflow change to All

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, content-type, reusable-workflow

Yesterday I have created reusable workflow using custom content type in SharePoint online.
today I have open that reusable workflow from SharePoint designer 2013, then  found that custom content type that I have associated to it get change to All.

[image]

I don't know why this happen.
then I am tried to attached custom content type to that workflow , but the button is not enable.

[image]

please suggest some solutions.

i don't want to do rework.

Comment: What versions are you using? I'm having the same issue with SPD 15.0.4787.1000, MSO 15.0.4823.1000 and SP 15.0.0.4727.

Comment: my SharePoint designer version Is 15.0.4420.1017

Comment: I see no many answer... also googleing did not help and MS - as for the majority of bugs - ignores it. I am having the same problem, but I also realized that the WF seems to keep its functionalities even if the Content Type disappeared. Yes, if you have to develop it it is unpleasant because you have to copy all steps one by one and redo the connections...
If you found a better workaround, please share!

Comment: i am also getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The "Associate to Content Type" option will be enabled only if you are creating a reusable workflow using SharePoint 2010 workflow platform.

From SP 2013 and in the SP Online this option is no more available. Once you create a reusable workflow you can only associate to only a List/Library.

This change is giving an ability to avoid the association to only content types in a specific list but not all.

Below screenshot if you are creating a reusable workflow with 2013 workflow platform.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When creating a reusable SharePoint 2013 workflow from SharePoint Designer using the Ribbon, you are unable to bind it to a content type.

The (very silly) workaround to this is to create the workflow from the File menu as follows.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is a pic with a workflow 2013 you're showing. As far as I know only 2010 workflows can be associated with a specific content type...